# Feature scaling and when to use which

Tags: regression, normalization, scales, multidimensional-scaling, data-preprocessing

I am looking into running regression on a multivariate data set. I am looking into different ways to scale my data: standardization, L2 and L1 normalizations.

In what case would you use which method?

Thanks

Comment: By L2 and L1 normalization, do you mean *regularization*? As in shrinkage with ridge and LASSO?

Comment: L2 and L1 are used for regularization but can also be used for scaling your dataset. 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling

Comment: ...by which you mean, for L2 that you scale all your feature vectors to lie on the unit sphere? And by L1 on the unit L1-norm-surface?

Comment: exactly. it is used many time when preprocessing data for machine learning.  I couln't however find an analysis on when each method works best.